# xlsxwriter conditional format formula with multiple criteria

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to my excel file using `xlsxwriter`, but not sure how to code for two conditions. After perusing the documentation I only see examples for one.

Concretely I'm trying to say when the value (H13) is greater than (H5) **AND** > (H6) then color green.

Below is my attempt that does not work. I believe this is simply a syntax issue.

```
worksheet.conditional_format('H13:H13', {'type': 'formula',
                                         'criteria': '=H13 >= $H$5 and H13 > $H$6 ',
                                         'format': green_bg})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all cases like this it is best to figure out the conditional format in Excel first and then transfer it across to xlsxwriter.

Excel doesn't allow joined/union conditional format conditions like your example. Instead you would need to use something like `AND()`. Like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('conditional_format.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

green_bg = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE',
                                 'font_color': '#006100'})


worksheet.write('H5', 2)
worksheet.write('H6', 5)
worksheet.write('H13', 9)

worksheet.conditional_format('H13:H13', {'type': 'formula',
                                        'criteria': '=AND($H$13 >= $H$5, $H$13 > $H$6)',
                                        'format': green_bg})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

However, the logical statement here is a little suspect. It is actually just the same as `$H$13 > $H$6`. Maybe you meant to say `..., $H$13 < $H$6`.